# Do i have to unsubscribe from anonymous event handlers of local variables?

Tags: c#, .net, events, event-handling

If I have a code that looks something like this:

```
public void Foo()
{
    Bar bar = new Bar();

    bar.SomeEvent += (sender, e) =>
    {
        //Do something here
    };

    bar.DoSomeOtherThingAndRaiseSomeEvent();
}
```

Will `bar` be collected when the method runs out of the scope, or will I have to manually unsubscribe from the event to prevent a memory leak because of a reference to `SomeEvent`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your situation is fine; the event *subscriber* will not prevent the *publisher* from being collected, but the opposite can happen.

For example,

```
class Foo
{
    public event EventHandler FooEvent;

    void LeakMemory()
    {
        Bar bar = new Bar();

        bar.AttachEvent(this);
    }
}

class Bar
{
    void AttachEvent(Foo foo)
    {
        foo.FooEvent += (sender, e) => { };
    }
}
```

In this case, the instance of `Bar` created within `LeakMemory` can't be collected until either

- The anonymous method represented by the lambda is removed from `FooEvent`'s invocation list
- The instance of Foo to which it's attached can be collected

This is because the event (which is just some syntactic sugar over an ordinary `delegate` instance) holds onto a list of delegates to invoke when it's invoked, and each of these delegates has, in turn, a reference to the object that it's attached to (in this case, the instance of `Bar`).

Note that we're only talking about collection *eligibility* here. Just because it's eligible doesn't say anything about *when* (or even, really, *if*) it will be collected, just that it *can* be.

Comment: Is there any standard form/idiom of "weak-reference events"?

Comment: @pst: Unfortunately, no. This is something that's been discussed before (more generally, simply not considering references that are *only* part of delegates as being reachable), but the complexities and potential pitfalls have thus far prevented it from being implemented. There may have been changes to those plans since I last looked, but as far as I know this is where things stand and will continue to. Even solutions that use the `WeakReference` class just move the issue to another type.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the object `bar` refers won't be automatically garbage collected immediately... it's just that the `bar` variable won't *prevent* it from being garbage collected.

The event handler won't prevent the instance of `Bar` from being garbage collected either though - the "normal" problem is that an event handler keeps the *subscriber* of an event from being garbage collected (if it uses an instance method or captures "this" in an anonymous function). It doesn't usually affect the *publisher* being garbage collected. Just remember that the publisher needs to keep a reference to all the subscribers - the subscriber doesn't need to remember what it's subscribed to, unless it explicitly wants to unsubscribe or use some other member later.

Assuming nothing else is keeping your instance of `Bar` alive, your code should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The above answers are correct; I just wanted to make a note. Anonymous delegates used as handlers can only be unsubscribed if you retain some other reference to the delegate/lambda. This is because lambdas are "function literals", kind of like string literals, however unlike strings they are NOT compared semantically when determining equality:

```
public event EventHandler MyEvent;

...

//adds a reference to this named method in the context of the current instance
MyEvent += Foo;

//Adds a reference to this anonymous function literal to MyEvent
MyEvent += (s,e) => Bar();

...

//The named method of the current instance will be the same reference
//as the named method.
MyEvent -= Foo;

//HOWEVER, even though this lambda is semantically equal to the anonymous handler, 
//it is a different function literal and therefore a different reference,
//which will not match the anonymous handler.
MyEvent -= (s,e) => Bar();

var hasNoHandlers = MyEvent == null; //false

//To successfully unsubscribe a lambda, you have to keep a reference handy:

EventHandler myHandler = (s,e) => Bar();

MyEvent += myHandler;

...

//the variable holds the same reference we added to the event earlier,
//so THIS call will remove the handler.
MyEvent -= myHandler;
```