# Unsubscribe from events in observableCollection

Tags: c#

Lets say I have an observableCollection of classes:

```
CustomClassName testClass = new CustomClassName();
ObservableCollection<CustomClassName> collection = new ObservableCollection<CustomClassName>();
testClass.SomeEvent += OnSomeEvent;
collection.add(testClass);
```

When I will remove items from a collection, do i need manually unsubscribe from events(OnSomeEvent) or should I leave it for a GC? 
And what is the best way to unsubscribe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you expect your item to be collected then yes you need to unsubscribe.

To do so, the usual way is:

```
collection.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(collection_CollectionChanged);

// ...
// and add the method
void collection_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
    {
        foreach (var it in e.OldItems) {
            var custclass = it as CustomClassName;
            if (custclass != null) custclass.SomeEvent -= OnSomeEvent;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thnx. And what is the best way? I am doing it in collectionChanged.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to unsubscribe in normal case.

The event *subscriber* cannot prevent the *publisher* (`testClass`) from being collected, but the opposite can happen. I cannot see anything keeping the `testClass` alive, except the `ObservableCollection`.

```
testClass.SomeEvent += this.OnSomeEvent;
```

`testClass` is keeping `this` alive because `this` is stored in `testClass.SomeEvent`'s invocation list (such that `OnSomeEvent` is called when there is a `SomeEvent`). `this` will not keep `testClass` alive by subscribing `testClass`'s event.

In the following code, the `obj` is removed from the collection, and it is garbage collected *without unsubscribing*, you may try to run the code to see the result:

```
void Main()
{
    var obj = new BackgroundWorker();
    obj.DoWork += OnSomeEvent;
    var oc = new ObservableCollection<object>{ obj };

    WeakReference objRef = new WeakReference(obj);
    Console.WriteLine(objRef.IsAlive);

    oc.Remove(obj);
    obj = null;
    GC.Collect();

    Console.WriteLine(objRef.IsAlive);
}

private void OnSomeEvent(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{   
    Console.WriteLine("work");
}
```

Output:

> True
>   False

You may take a look in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081638/do-i-have-to-unsubscribe-from-anonymous-event-handlers-of-local-variables?rq=1).

Comment: what you mean by normal case?

Comment: Because the += operator can be "overloaded", so anything can happen. If it is just subscribing an event, it should be fine.

Comment: @Sasha I added some code, you may try if it is your case.